Linear Algebra Done Right (4th edition) - Problem 23 of section 6A
I'm struggling with the problem 23 of section 6A from the 4th edition of Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right":

Suppose $v_1,\ldots,v_m \in V$ are such that $\|v\|\leq 1$ for each $k=1,\ldots,m$. Show that there exist $a_1,\ldots,a_m\in\{1,-1\}$ such that
$$\|a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_m v_m \| \leq \sqrt{m}$$

So far I have tried to express the squared norm and get the following upper bound:
$$
\|a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_m v_m \|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^m |a_i|^2 \|v_i\|^2 + \sum_{j,k \\ j\neq k}^m 
a_j a_k \langle v_j, v_k \rangle \leq m + \sum_{j,k \\ j\neq k}^m 
a_j a_k \langle v_j, v_k \rangle
$$
I think I need to show that there exist $a_1,\ldots,a_m\in\{1,-1\}$ such that the sum in the right hand side of the inequality above will be negative or zero. But I cannot figure out how to do it. Or maybe I need to use some other properties of the inner products and/or norms?
Thanks in advance.

Have you tried mathematical induction?
